# Where did the Vilna Gaon praise remaining silent?

Tags: sources-mekorot, loud-quiet, vilna-gaon

I once heard someone quote the [Vilna Gaon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) saying, “For every second that one remains silent he will merit reward of a magnitude that is beyond the comprehension of even of *malochim* (celestial beings).

Does anyone know the source for this?

Comment: Please [edit] in as much information as you can about where you heard this, and why you are interested in finding its source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [Igeres Hagra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50908&st=&pgnum=246)

> וכל רגע ורגע שהאדם חוסם פיו זוכה בשבילו לאור הגנוז שאין מלאך ובריה
>   יכולים לשער